# How can I make ExtJS treecolumn scroll horizontally only the content and not the header

Tags: javascript, extjs, scrollbar, treegrid

Let's assume I have a tree grid with a single column, the treecolumn. The width of the panel is 200px, and when expanding, some records have a wider text than 200px. Currently, Ext will apply an ellipsis property on those cells. What I want to do is to show horizontal scrollbar in the bottom which will update at every expand/collapse event. To accomplish this I used column `autoSize()` function which increase the column size to fit the content and automatically show the scrollbar in the bottom. But, increasing the column width increase also the column header width, which I don't want. Is there a way to keep the header width at 200px and increase only the column content width, keeping the scrollbar in the bottom?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, there isn't. At least not in such a way that you can be sure not to unintentionally break anything deep inside the framework.

Comment: Good & bad. Good to know. Bad because in this case I'll try to manage something at the CSS level.

Comment: CSS won't work, because the table is done using DIVs. HTML doesn't know that the grid is a table at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a way, but as @Alexander suggests in his comment, I had to enter the Ext code and mess with it. In fact what I've done was to remove the horizontal scroll partner corresponding to header as follows:

```
var headerScroll = myTree.getDockedItems()[0].getScrollable();

mytree.getView().getScrollable().removePartner(headerScroll, "x");
```

`removePartner()` is a private function so I should not use it, but in this particular case I don't think will harass the rest of the code.